# Create a new page in React with React Router

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router, react-router-dom

I've followed the documentation but maybe I have a typo in my code or something because it's not working.

In index.js:

```
ReactDOM.render(
  <BrowserRouter>
    <App />
  </BrowserRouter>,
  document.getElementById('root')
);
```

App.js:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Route } from 'react-router-dom';
import Page from './Page';
import './App.css';
class App extends Component {
  state = {
    response: '',
    post: '',
    responseToPost: '',
  };
  componentDidMount() {
    this.getData();
  }

  getData = async () => {
    const response = await fetch('/api/world', {
      method: 'POST',
      headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
      },
      body: JSON.stringify({ post: this.state.post }),
    });
    const body = await response.text();
    this.setState({ responseToPost: body });
  };
  render() {
    return (
      <div className='App'>
        <p>{this.state.response}</p>
        <Router>
          <Route
            exact
            path='/pages'
            component={<Page response={this.state.responseToPost} />}
          />
        </Router>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
export default App;
```

and Page component:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import './App.css';
class Page extends Component {
  render() {
    return <div dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{ __html: this.props.response }} />;
  }
}
export default Page;
```

There is nothing loading on those pages. What is wrong?

Data is coming from the server for sure, if it is shown in App.js it's fine but it doesn't work when I send it to Page.

Comment: What is the `responseToPost` state after it is fetched?

Comment: @ChunkyChunk I don't understand the question

Comment: When the App component is rendered for the first time, its state contains a property `responseToPost` that is initialized as an empty string. Then, when the App component is mounted, an HTTP request is executed which, when finished, sets the value of `responseToPost` to `text()` from the HTTP response. What is the new value of the `responseToPost` state property?  A better question - what is the complete `App` state when the HTTP request is executed?

Answer (score 0):

you need to replace the router tag

```
<Router>
```

use switch tag instead that should work

```
<Switch>
```

So like this

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Route } from 'react-router-dom';
import Page from './Page';
import './App.css';
class App extends Component {
  state = {
    response: '',
    post: '',
    responseToPost: '',
  };
  componentDidMount() {
    this.getData();
  }

  getData = async () => {
    const response = await fetch('/api/world', {
      method: 'POST',
      headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
      },
      body: JSON.stringify({ post: this.state.post }),
    });
    const body = await response.text();
    this.setState({ responseToPost: body });
  };
  render() {
    return (
      <div className='App'>
        <p>{this.state.response}</p>
        <Switch>
          <Route
            exact
            path='/pages'
            component={<Page response={this.state.responseToPost} />}
          />
        </Switch>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
export default App;
```

Comment: `Switch` is not required here.  OP just wants to see their single `Route` rendered.  EX:  https://reactrouter.com/web/api/Route/component